# How to use Pandoc's writeHtmlString when using IO String for template

Tags: haskell, pandoc

I am reading the template file when converting markdown files to html files and trying to get IO to play nice with pure system.

```
template :: IO String
template = readFile "/File/Path/template.html"

siteOptions :: WriterOptions
siteOptions = def { writerStandalone = True, writerTemplate = template }

convertMdtoHtml :: FilePath -> IO () 
convertMdtoHtml file = do
  contents <- readFile file 
  let pandoc = readMarkdown def contents
  let html = writeHtmlString siteOptions pandoc
  writeFile (file ++ ".html") html
```

Here is the Documentation for the writeHtmlString that I am trying to use http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/pandoc/1.11.1/doc/html/Text-Pandoc-Writers-HTML.html

The error I get when trying to run this is

```
 Couldn't match expected type `String' with actual type `IO String'
```

Is there any way to do this in haskell or do I need to have the template file as a string already in the code.

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make `template` a parameter of `siteOptions`:

```
siteOptions :: String -> WriterOptions
siteOptions template = def { writerStandalone = True, writerTemplate = template }

convertMdtoHtml :: FilePath -> IO () 
convertMdtoHtml file = do
  ...
  template <- readFile "/File/Path/template.html"
  let html = writeHtmlString (siteOptions template) pandoc
```

The value `template :: IO String` is an **IO action** - a piece of impure (side-effecting) code, that, when executed, will produce a result of type `String`. That's why you can't use it in the context where a `String` is expected.

If you want to include the contents of `"/File/Path/template.html"` in your program during compile-time, consider using [Template Haskell](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Template_Haskell):

```
> :set -XTemplateHaskell
> import Language.Haskell.TH.Syntax
> import Language.Haskell.TH.Lib
> let str = $(stringE =<< (runIO (readFile "/path/to/foo")))
> str
"bar\n"
> :t str
str :: [Char]
```

Comment: Thanks Mikhail for answering so quickly. I think was looking to much in the details and forgot the overall picture. Thanks for the additional details on TemplateHaskell, I think something like that is overkill for what I am trying to do.